Read only the structure of a geopackage using GDAL/OGR?
I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to only show the structure (layer names, field names and types, constraints, etc) of a GeoPackage which has no data record using GDAL/OGR (ogrinfo).
Is it possible?
If not, do you know any other open source solution to achieve the same task on Ubuntu?
I currently have:
# ogrinfo mydata.gpkg 
INFO: Open of `mydata.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.

with: GDAL 3.9.0dev-336811c7257a31f59b4f11292fa4691716bb8ace, released 2024/01/26 

Did you try -so -al -ro as arguments to ogrinfo?

Yes, e.g. with -ro I'm facing: FAILURE: Unable to open datasource 'mydata.gpkg' with the following drivers.

Odd, just the other 2 then

According to https://www.geopackage.org/guidance/getting-started.html :

A GeoPackage is an SQLite Database file with a .gpkg extension. If you are unsure whether a file is an SQLite database, you can use a binary or text editor to view the starting bytes of the file and see if they state SQLite format 3.

So, using the sqlite3 CLI one can run:

sqlite3 file.gpkg to log into the database

Now, from the sqlite3 console one can list database, tables and schemas as follow:

.databases        # list databases
.tables ?TABLE?   # List names of tables matching LIKE pattern TABLE
.schema ?PATTERN? # Show the CREATE statements matching PATTERN

More with .help
Exit sqlite3 with .exit
